# Java replace integer in precompiled class

Tags: java

I have a class in another jar with a method compiled like this:

```
public final class DecompiledClass {

  public void doSomething() {
        MyObject b = new MyObject()
                .option( Option.TIMEOUT, 5000 )
                .remoteAddress( target.getAddress() );
  }

}
```

The person who made this class didn't allow for the value of **5000** to be configurable. How can I modify this value without the source, externally?

Comment: Short answer: "Not easily".

Comment: I can think of 2 options: 1) Modify the decompiled Java code, recompile it, and use it, or 2) extend the `DecompiledClass` and override the `doSomething()` method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen class as shown is final, so you can't extend it, which leaves option 1...

Comment: I didn't see the `final` keyword, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Maybe use a Decorator? Delegate all but doSeomething() to the decorated class, copy the decompiled code, write it on your own? Maybe....

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I simply edited the class in a new eclipse project using the same package path. Then when I exported I included the original jar and eclipse extracted it into my new jar.

Comment: I used the decompiled code and fixed any issues with it.